# Proving $v$, $T(v)$, $T^2(v)$ is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the following:

Given that $V$ is a vector space, with $dim V = 3$, and $T: V \to V$ is a linear map with the properties $T^2(v) \neq 0$ and $T^3(v) = 0$, with $v \in V$, show that $v, T(v), T^2(v)$ is a basis for V. I'm free to assume the axiom of choice, so V has some basis.

This is my work so far:

First of all $V$ contains more than ${0}$ or else, $T^2(v)$ would be $0$. 
Also $T(v) \neq 0$ for if $T(v) = 0$ then, $T(T(v)) = T(0) = 0$.

I simply want to prove that $av + bT(v) + cT^2(v) = 0$ has only $a = b = c = 0$ as a solution.

Doing this case by case gives:

Assuming that $av = bT(v) + cT^2(v) = T(bv) + T^2(cv)$ gives $T^2(av) = T^3(bv) = 0$, contradiction.

Assuming $aT(v) = bv + cT^2(v)$ gives the same contradiction after running T twice.

Assuming $aT^2(v) = bv + cT(v)$ gives $0 = T(bv) + T^2(cv)  \Rightarrow T(bv) = T^2(-bv) \Rightarrow T^2(bv) = 0$, again a contradiction.

How legitimate is this? It certainly feels very clumbsy. Is there any way to go directly 
$av + bT(v) + cT^2(v) = 0 \Rightarrow a = b = c = 0$??

Did I miss something?

Any appropriate theory, if applicable, is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated above there exists $v \in V$ such that $T(v),T^2(v) \neq 0$.

We consider $a T^2(v)+b T(v)+c v=0$ We want to show that $a=b=c=0$.

$a T^2(v)+b T(v)+c v=0$ applying the linear map T on both sides two times yields:

1) $0=T(a T^2(v)+b T(v)+cv)=a T^3(v)+b T^2(v)+cT(v)=bT^2(v)+cT(v)$, since $(T^3=0)$

2) $0=bT^3(v)+cT^2(v)=cT^2(v)$, so $c=0$ , because $T^2(v) \neq 0$

From 1) it follows now that $0=bT^2(v)+cT(v)=bT^2(v)$, so $b=0$.

Similarly it follows that $a=0$

Comment: Clear and concise! Thanks! :)

Comment: Your welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Your working is indeed correct.There is a neater way:

Hint: consider $T^2(av + bT(v) + cT^2(v))$ and then $T(av + bT(v) + cT^2(v))$